# Obfuscating .cs source itself in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, obfuscation

My company has an `ASP.NET` website (*not* web app). All the tools we have looked at only obfuscate `DLL` or `EXE` files (not the source). What we need is a tool to obfuscate the *source itself* (`.cs`); preferably in Visual Studio. Changing the names of everything is *not* an option. So again, is there any *source level* obfuscator?

Comment: Why are you distributing the source code if you don't want anybody to read it?

Comment: Why can't you just precompile the website and then obfuscate that?

Comment: Becuase the website is already done as a website and not a web application so the information is not on .dll files it's on the .aspx files and I can't migrate or change it now, it's a very large application. So I am looking for a way to rename the variables at least, without doing it so manually.

Comment: Why do you care about the variables names after the website is deployed???

Comment: Because I want to prevent further changes to the code.

Comment: Just precompile the deployed site, all the text from *.aspx files will go away to *.dlls automatically. This is why precomplication has been introduced!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See our [C# Obfuscator](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Obfuscators/CSharpObfuscator.html) tool.  Operates on Souce files.

Answer (score 1):

First step would be to refactor to inline variables and methods (unless it defects performance) and rename them to some random unmeaningful letters and numbers.
I'd suggest using Resharper.

(inlining in this context means inline as the Resharper refactoring functionality)

Comment: Yes, but is there some application out there that will allow me to do this automatically, without renaming the variables one by one?

Comment: Resharper will rename a single variable/method all over the solution, but if you want a single click process - I don't know a program that does that, but it should be fairly simple to write one real quick (thanks for the project idea)

Answer (score 0):

For locking application and code obsuscation i use intellilock, is not free but is good.

Comment: I need To obfuscate a .cs file not a .dll or .exe. I need to deliver the source code but I want the c# files to be obfuscated.

Comment: If you want to send a .cs file somewhere you can zip them with a password, sorry if i don`t understand but i don`t get the problem

Comment: For example, I want to rename all the variables in my solution but still hand over the .cs files. I want my code to be NON understandable, but still to give it away.

Comment: I don't want to rename the variables manually by refractor or by using resharper. Is there a way to sort of obfuscate the shore but no the compile files.

Comment: Ok i think i understood now! see this '.NET Reactor' is not free. Incl. support for ASP.NET